# Trying to use PIP for python in CMD and getting "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: python

I see that this has been asked before but the solution did not work for me.  When entering PIP into the command prompt I get 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I located pip.exe at C:\Users\ZachPC\Anaconda3\Scripts and tried adding that to the path environment variable and it still gives me the same error in the command prompt.

I am not sure why I am still not able to use PIP after adding the path to environment variables path in the control panel.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jupyter notes, try "!pip ...." as the beginning of the command.

Comment: I like using the Spyder IDE does this still apply?

Comment: this is what cmd gave me: '!pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Sorry, that's all I know about this error. Hope some else could provide a better answer.